# Homeomorphic spaces $I^n \times \{0\} \cup \partial(I^n) \times I$ and $I^n \times \{0\}$

Tags: general-topology

I think that the two spaces $I^n \times \{0\} \cup \partial(I^n) \times I$ and $I^n \times \{0\}$ where $I = [0,1]$ are homeomorphic. It makes sense to me because for example in the case $n=2$ the first space is just the boundary of the cube without the face on top. But I don't know how I can find the homeomorphism between them.

Comment: Yes indeed. They are both homeomorphic to a closed $n$-ball or, equivalently, to $I^n$. Constructing an explicit homeomorphism is a bit annoying to do, but is doable. I would indeed consider the case $n=2$ first, construct an explicit homeomerphism in that case, and then generalize.

Comment: One idea I have is to consider the center of the cube, call it $O$, and consider the sphere centered at $O$ which passes through the vertices of the cube, and then use radial projections from $O$. This may get you started, I hope.

Comment: Another take, related to Malkoun's idea, is to embed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and compose stereographic projection from $(0, 2)$ with a dilation of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $J = [-1,1]$. Then clearly $J^n$ is homeomorphic to $I^n$ and $J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I$ is homeomorphic to $I^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial I^n \times I$. Moreover, $J^n \approx [-2,2]^n$, hence it suffices to show that $J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I \approx [-2,2]^n$.

Note that $\lVert (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \rVert = \max_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i \rvert$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^n$. We have $J^n = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid  \lVert x \rVert \le 1 \}$, $[-2,2]^n = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid  \lVert x \rVert \le 2 \}$ and $\partial J^n = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid  \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$.

Stereographic projection of $J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I$ from $(0,2) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is given by
$$\phi : J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I \to \mathbb  R^n, \phi(x,t) = \frac{2}{2-t}x $$
which clearly is a continuous map.

1. $\phi$ is injective: Let $(x,t) \ne (x',t')$. If $t = t'$, then $x \ne x'$ and thus $\phi(x,t) =  \frac{2}{2-t}x \ne  \frac{2}{2-t}x' = \frac{2}{2-t'}x' = \phi(x',t')$. If $t \ne t'$ we may assume w.lo.g. that $ t > t'$. This implies $t > 0$ and $x  \in \partial J^n$ so that $\lVert \phi(x,t) \rVert =  \frac{2}{2-t} \lVert x \rVert =  \frac{2}{2-t} > \frac{2}{2-t'} \ge \frac{2}{2-t'} \lVert x' \rVert = \lVert \phi(x',t') \rVert$, hence in particular $\phi(x,t) \ne \phi/x',t')$.
2. $\phi( J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I) = [-2,2]^n$: First note that we have $\lVert \phi(x,t) \rVert = \frac{2}{2-t} \lVert x \rVert \le \frac{2}{2-t} \le 2$, i.e. $\phi(x,t) \in [-2,2]^n$. Next, let $y \in [-2,2]^n$. If $y \in J^n$ , then $y = \phi(y,0) \in \phi( J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I)$. If $y \notin J^n$, then $1 < \lVert y \rVert \le 2$. Define $x = \frac{y}{\lVert y \rVert}$ and $t = 2 -\frac{2}{\lVert y \rVert}$. Then $(x,t) \in \partial J^n \times I$ and $\phi(x,t) = y$.

Thus $\phi$ maps $ J^n \times \{ 0\} \cup \partial J^n \times I$ homeomorphically onto $[-2,2]^n$.